# HTML Input - Select Multiple Images and View Them in Page?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, input, upload

I have the following html code, which allow you to select Multiple files:

```
<input id="uploadFiles" type="file" name="myfiles" multiple="multiple" onchange="selectMulitableFiles(this)">
```

here is the onchange funcion:

```
function selectMulitableFiles(e) {
    $.each(e.files, function () {
        var tempelete = '<tr><td><img onload="loadImage(this);" alt="" src=' + this.name + ' style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></td></tr>';
        $("#tblImages tbody").append(tempelete);
    });
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is to view all these selected images to the images that i generate and then write inside a control, but e.value will give you only the fake path. 
Is what i am trying to do possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here if ur solution 
you need to use `FileReader()`  to give image src ..

```
function selectMulitableFiles(e) {
    $.each(e.files, function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
      var tempelete = '<tr><td><img onload="loadImage(this);" alt="" src=' + e.target.result + ' style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; width: 60px; height: 60px;" /></td></tr>';
        $("#tblImages tbody").append(tempelete);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);

    });
}
```

[**JSBIN Example**](http://jsbin.com/todudadi/1/)

Comment: Your solution is perfect, just change e.files[0] to "this". thx